# Adding a comma to the end of every row in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a list of sample codes which I input into a website to get information about each of them (they are codes for stars, but it doesn't matter what the codes are, they are just a long string of numbers). All these numbers are in one column, one number per row. The website I need to input this file into accepts the numbers to still be in a column, but with a comma next to the numbers. This is an example: 
Instead of:

> 164891738509173
>
> 184818483848283
>
> 18483943491u385

It's supposed to look like this:

> 164891738509173,
>
> 184818483848283,
>
> 18483943491u385,

I wanted to program a quick python code to do that automatically for each number in the entire column. How do I do that? I can manage theoretically to do that manually if the number of stars I'm dealing with is little, but unfortunately in the website, I need to input something like 60000 stars (so 60000 of these numbers) so doing it manually is suicide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
open('output.txt', 'w').writelines(  # open 'output.txt' for writing and write multiple lines
    line.rstrip('\n') + ',\n'  # append comma to each line
    for line in open('input.txt')  # read lines with numbers from 'input.txt'
)
```

You *could* do it more idiomatically and use a `with` block, but that's probably overkill for such a small task:

```
with open('input.txt') as In, open('output.txt', 'w') as Out:
    for line in In:
        Out.write(line.rstrip('\n') + ',\n')
```

Comment: Thank you!! Worked like a charm! Do you think it's possible for it to read .tsv files as well? I can always change the format it takes 2 seconds but just wondering. It's just that I download all these files as .tsv automatically.

Comment: If their format is like described in your questions, then yes, you should be able to read them too

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

If you want to add comma at end the every entry during printing, you can do this:

```py
>>> codes = ['164891738509173', '184818483848283', '18483943491u385']
>>> for code in codes:
...     print(code, end=',\n')
... 
164891738509173,
184818483848283,
18483943491u385,
```

To add a comma to every item within the list,

```py
>>> end_comma = [f"{code}," for code in codes]
>>> end_comma
['164891738509173,', '184818483848283,', '18483943491u385,']
```

Comment: Yes, exactly I would like to have the comma added to every item within the list. Thank you this worked as well!